# iPhone 7 - Can't update apps

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, ios-appstore, apple-id

When I try to update an app, it says **Verification Required**, and when I try to fill in my PayPal account, it declines due to an issue with my PayPal account, and I think the same problem applies to credit and debit cards (I don't have a credit or debit card).

I tried reading many tutorials, and people who had the same issue as me, and none seemed to have fixed my issue. (I can't choose **None** when I try to edit my Apple ID payment information, and I don't own a iTunes gift card or a Mac.) I am clueless, and confused. I really need some help.

Comment: Do you mind creating a new/separate Apple ID for app store purchases?

Comment: It might help to know what exactly you have tried so far, otherwise people will recommend the same things again. Please add some links to the tutorials etc you‘ve tried, and explain where they didn‘t work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

If you can‘t select „None“ you must enter some payment details to re-enable your account. So either get your PayPal account fixed, create a new PayPal account, or get a credit card (or ask Antriebs to help you out with one).

If all these options are unavailable to you right now you can try tinsort it out with Apple Support. Contact details depend by country etc but can be found at the bottom of [apple,com](https://www.apple.com/).

Answer (score 1):

There is a pending charge from iTunes on your account. This may be a monthly subscription (iCloud storage, Apple Music, etc) or an app, movie, song, book, something purchased from the iTunes or App Store(s). Whatever card information was on file at the time of this purchase is the card information that the Verification Required is looking for.

To reiterate, if you had credit card information on file but no longer have access to that card, you are in a bit of a pickle because entering other bank information or even an iTunes gift card to relieve that pending charge does NOT work, in my experience. I hope this helps.

Note: if the charge is a pending subscription, there should be an email from Apple with "Update payment information to [continue service]" in the subject line.